# Multirobot + laser rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, laser, hokuyo, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some troubles to see the laser_scan in a simulation with two robots which have the same description file (urdf) in different group with different namespace.

I launch both in gazebo and works quite good, the robots looks ok but when I launch rviz to see the laser, I select the fixed frame and the target frame of the robot one, I select the robot_description of the robot one and the tfprefix of the robot one. The tf looks great.

I see the robot one in the center of the visual space in rviz. When I try to see the laser_scan, I select the correct topic but I nothing appear, the error is the next:

```
Transform [sender=/gazebo]
For frame [hokuyo_laser_link]: Frame [hokuyo_laser_link] does not exist
```

I think the problem come to rviz. Rviz look for the frame described in the urdf robot description and not look for the tf_prefix.

Here my launch file and my tree of tf:

```
<launch>
  <!-- send summit_xl.urdf to param server -->
  <group ns="summit_one">
      <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find summit_xl_description)/urdf/summit_xl.urdf" />
      <node name="spawn_summit" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.5 -model summit_xl_one" respawn="false" output="screen">        
      </node>

      <!-- Controller manager parameters -->
      <param name="pr2_controller_manager/mechanism_statistics_publish_rate" value="1.0" />
      <param name="pr2_controller_manager/joint_state_publish_rate" value="100.0" />

      <!-- Robot state publisher -->
      <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="summit_one_state_publisher" output="screen">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
        <remap from="hokuyo_laser_link" to="summit_one/hokuyo_laser_link" />
        <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="summit_one" />
      </node>

      <!-- Diagnostics -->
      <node pkg="pr2_mechanism_diagnostics" type="pr2_mechanism_diagnostics" name="pr2_mechanism_diagnostics_one" />
      
      <rosparam file="$(find summit_xl_ctrl)/summit_xl_ctrl.yaml" command="load"/>
      <param name="pr2_controller_manager/joint_state_publish_rate" value="100.0" />
      <node name="summit_xl_ctrl" pkg="pr2_controller_manager" type="spawner" args="summit_xl_ctrl" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
      <node pkg="summit_xl_odometry" type="summit_xl_odometry" name="summit_xl_odometry_node" output="screen"/>   
  </group>

  <group ns="summit_two">     
      <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find summit_xl_description)/urdf/summit_xl.urdf" />
      <node name="spawn_summit" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -x 2.0 -y 2.0 -z 0.5 -model summit_xl_two" respawn="false" output="screen" />

      <!-- Controller manager parameters -->
      <param name="pr2_controller_manager/mechanism_statistics_publish_rate" value="1.0" />
      <param name="pr2_controller_manager/joint_state_publish_rate" value="100.0" />

      <!-- Robot state publisher -->
      <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="summit_two_state_publisher" output="screen">
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
        <!--remap from="joint_states" to="summit_one/joint_states" /-->
        <param name="tf_prefix" type="string" value="summit_two" />
      </node>

      <!-- Diagnostics -->
      <node pkg="pr2_mechanism_diagnostics" type="pr2_mechanism_diagnostics" name="pr2_mechanism_diagnostics_two" />  

      <rosparam file="$(find summit_xl_ctrl)/summit_xl_ctrl.yaml" command="load"/>
      <param name="pr2_controller_manager/joint_state_publish_rate" value="100.0" />
      <node name="summit_xl_ctrl" pkg="pr2_controller_manager" type="spawner" args="summit_xl_ctrl" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
      <node pkg="summit_xl_odometry" type="summit_xl_odometry" name="summit_xl_odometry_node" output="screen"/> 
  </group> 

</launch>
```

[tf http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xngh01&s=6](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xngh01&s=6)
tf:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xngh01&s=6

Someone who has the same problem? What should I do with the ghost frames? Is there any way to tell what frame rviz should choose?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40397/multirobot-+-laser-rviz/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2012-08-02**:
Ok, at last I find the solution. When the tree of tf works fine, we need to lauch rviz node with param like this:   and another rviz node with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No this is not at all the rviz error. The issue comes from the *gazebo_plugins* package and in your particular case from the *gazebo_ros_laser* plugin.

Current implementation in *gazebo_ros_laser.cpp* is as follows:

```
240: // Add Frame Name
241: this->laserMsg.header.frame_id = this->frameName;
```

and earlier

```
100: this->frameName = _sdf->GetElement("frameName")->GetValueString();
```

This means that laser scans in the field *frame_id* of *LaserMsg* header got whatever you put in the *frameName* of your gazebo controller declared in urdf.

```
  <controller:gazebo_ros_laser name="gazebo_ros_laser_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_laser_relative.so">
    <hokuyoMinIntensity>101.0</hokuyoMinIntensity>
    <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>20</updateRate>
    <topicName>scan</topicName>
    <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
    <interface:laser name="gazebo_ros_laser_iface" />
  </controller:gazebo_ros_laser>
```

And therefore rviz looks how to tansform scans from the link *hokuyo_link* but it can only find */summit_one/hokuyo_link* and */summit_two/hokuyo_link*.

I can see in your launch file that you try to handle that with:

```
<remap from="hokuyo_laser_link" to="summit_one/hokuyo_laser_link" />
```

but remapping works only for nodes and topics names, not for tf transformations, we use *tf_prefix* for that.

The  quick and dirty workaround for your problem is to make two copies of your urdf file: one declaring */summit_one/hokuyo_link* as *frameName* and the other with */summit_two/hokuyo_link*.

However the proper solution is to introduce tf resolving in *gazebo_ros_laser* before storing *frame_id* in message header.

This discussion is also valid for the rest of plugins in *gazebo_plugins* package. I will issue a ticket for this.

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-08-02**:
With the double urdf description and later with the laser patch you can visualize two robots at the same time in one rviz instance.

**Comment by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) on 2012-08-02**:
Ticket issued: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5511

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2012-08-03**:
Thanks a lot, I'm looking forward the next patch ;)

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2012-08-03**:
If I want use 20 equal robots, the replication of the urdf won't be the best solution. But, I think we start with 2 simple robots.